# append &showinfo=0 youtube api iframe src

Tags: php, jquery, youtube-api, append, joomla2.5

I have spent most of the day trying to find a way to easily append '&showinfo=0' to the end of an iframe src attribute - but have failed miserably.

I am building a Joomla site with the allvideos plugin which uses the youtube-api. I want to load the videos without the info-bar but can't find a way to remove it other than adding &showinfo=0 to the iframe src - so was hoping this was possible using jQuery as this is what I am used to using, but I do have some limited experience of php - so whatever works really.

EDIT

I have added a class to the iframe using jQuery then tried

```
(".hide-info").attr("src" +="&showinfo=0");
```

plus lots of variations on this theme, but its not working.

Comment: where is your work, code part etc?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the iframe already exists, then it has already loaded the embedded video, and changing the attributes with jQuery won't then reload what's inside the iframe.

I just had a quick peek at the source for the plugin you mention, and it seems pretty trivial to edit the PHP to do what you want; look for this block:

```
            if($plg_tag=="youtube"){
                $tagsource = preg_replace("~(http|https):(.+?)youtube.com\/watch\?v=~s","",$tagsource);
                $tagsourceYoutube = explode('&',$tagsource);
                $tagsource = $tagsourceYoutube[0];

                if(strpos($tagsource,'?')!==false){
                    $tagsource = $tagsource.'&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;wmode=transparent';
                } else {
                    $tagsource = $tagsource.'?rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;wmode=transparent';
                }
                if($final_autoplay=='true'){
                    $tagsource = $tagsource.'&amp;autoplay=1';
                }
            }
```

in the jw_allvideos.php file. After the last if block, but before the final curly brace, you could add this:

```
$tagsource = $tagsource.'&amp;showinfo=0';
```

Of course, that would lead to a plugin incompatible with future updates, so a more reliable way would be to create a patch that has that code which you could then apply any time you updated, but that's beyond the scope of this question.